# MySQL SUPER privilege vs. log_bin_trust_function_creators

Tags: mysql

With binary logging turned on for replication is it better to grant a user SUPER privilege when he/she is defining a stored procedure or UDF or is it better to set log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1 so the SUPER privilege is not required.

I have chosen the 2nd alternative but what is the "standard practice"?

Answer (score 4):

My preference is to set `log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1`  to avoid handing out the `SUPER` priviledge when it's not required for any other functionality. Appropriate permissions help protect against unknown SQL injection (i.e. user attempts to `DROP TABLE`) or theft of credentials.

Amazon RDS users must also use the second option as RDS does not allow the `SUPER` priviledge. There is an excellent write up on how to set the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` property on RDS instances [here](http://blog.peterdelahunty.com/2010/10/stored-procedures-on-amazon-rds.html).

Comment: Link is dead now, by the way.